# Nginx unable to validate JWT from cookie

Tags: nginx, jwt

I'd like to use this [nginx-jwt-module](https://github.com/max-lt/nginx-jwt-module) to restrict access to some of my routes.

this is how I set it up:

**nginx.conf**

```
server {
    auth_jwt_key "HELLO_WORLD";
    auth_jwt     off;

    location /secured-by-cookie/ {
        auth_jwt $cookie_auth;
        proxy_redirect off;

        rewrite test(.*)$ $1 break;
        proxy_pass http://backend-service/;

        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Server $remote_addr;

        # Mitigate httpoxy attack (see README for details)
        proxy_set_header Proxy "";
    }
}
```

Now I'm sure the token is correctly passed and read from the Cookie, but I'm still getting:

```
JWT: failed to parse jwt
```

error every time I'm sending a request with a JWT token in the request cookie.

So, now I think something may be wrong with the secret key that I'm using in the nginx.conf.
Maybe it's in wrong format? I also tried converting the string into hex format, but that didn't help either. Any ideas?

Comment: in my case it turned out to be a very long auth_jwt_key. After changing it to a shorter one, it all started to work.